# Error: Actions must be plain objects, Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I've spent a couple of days now searching for the answer to this and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have other projects set up in exactly the same way that are fetching data from api's fine. All other answers have said variations of how the actions need to return objects, which as far as I can tell mine are

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import Thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducers/reducer';
import App from './App';

import './css/index.css';
import './css/font-awesome.css';
import './css/bulma.css';

const logger = createLogger();
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(Thunk, logger));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Component calling mapDispatchToProps

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchRepositories } from '../actions/searchActions';

class Results extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.searchRepositories();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Some Stuff</div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    searchRepositories: () => {
      dispatch(searchRepositories());
    },
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    repositories: state.repositories,
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Results);
```

Reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';
import initialState from './INITIAL_STATE';


function reducer(prevState = initialState, action) {
  if (!action) return prevState;

  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_REPOS_REQUEST:
      return { ...prevState, loading: true };

    case types.FETCH_REPOS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...prevState,
        loading: false,
        repositories: action.data,
        error: '',
      };

    case types.FETCH_REPOS_ERROR:
      return { ...prevState, error: 'Encountered an error during GET request' };

    default:
      return prevState;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

action creator:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as types from './types';
import { ROOT } from '../config';


export function searchRepositoriesRequest() {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_REPOS_REQUEST,
  };
}

export function searchRepositoriesSuccess(repositories) {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_REPOS_SUCCESS,
    data: repositories,
  };
}

export function searchRepositoriesError(error) {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_REPOS_ERROR,
    data: error,
  };
}

export function searchRepositories() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(searchRepositoriesRequest());
    return axios.get(`${ROOT}topic:ruby+topic:rails`).then((res) => {
      dispatch(searchRepositoriesSuccess(res.data));
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch(searchRepositoriesError(err));
    });
  };
}
```

I have got this axios api request working using react this.state where I just put it in component did mount. If anyone can see where I am going wrong it would help me out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like I was using an earlier version of redux, which the version of redux-thunk I had installed, didn't like! I updated to the latest version of redux and it now calls as it should.

I'm still not sure why the other projects that have the older version installed still work...